# How do I fix the request that the form function is the issue

Tags: flask

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/logins",methods=["Post","GET"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form["name"]
        return redirect(url_for("user", usr=user))
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
@app.route("/<usr>")
def user(usr):
    return f"<h1>{usr}<h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The error says: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'name'

Comment: Show the form that's making the POST request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the request.form['name'], try this

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/logins",methods=["POST","GET"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form["login"]
        return redirect(url_for("user", usr=user))
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
@app.route("/<usr>")
def user(usr):
    return f"<h1>{usr}<h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

html form:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('login') }}" method="post">
<input name="login" placeholder="Login">
<input name="password" type="password" placeholder="password">
<button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```